# JavaScript replace regex starting with particular set of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace the words starting with `y-` with `test`, e.g:

```
This is a y-abc-def string
This is y-abc
```

Output I needed is:

```
This is a test string
This is test
```

I tried

```
inputString.replace(/(?:^|\W)y-(\w+)(?!\w)/g, 'test')
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
inputString = inputString.replace(/(^|\s)y-(\S*)(?!\w)/g, '$1test')
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF9eQ1/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
inputString.replace(/\by-\S*/g, "test")
```

Answer (score -1):

If ‘words’ means groups of `\w`s and hyphens, then this should do:

```
inputString.replace(/\by-[\w-]*/g, 'test')
```

I.e. word boundary, `y-` then a mix of word characters and hyphens.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
inputString.replace(/ y\-[\S]+/g, ' test')
```

On inputs:

```
> var inputString = "This is a y-abc-def string";
> inputString.replace(/ y\-[\S]+/g, ' test')
< "This is a test string"
```

Comment: What if there's a ‘`y-`-word’ at the very beginning of the string?

Comment: Why `[\S]` instead of just `\S`? And hyphens don't need escaped.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. Tested for followings:

```
var str = 'y-Thi$s is a y-ab-cdef y-ABC y-*&222 string y-4444';
console.log(str.replace(/(\s)?y-[^\s]+(\s)?/g,'$1test$2'));
```

Comment: `"any-string".replace(/(\s)?y-[^\s]+(\s)?/g,'$1test$2')` → `"antest"`

Comment: right :) in that case /\sy-[^\s]+(\s)?/ and will consider a starting space and remove later :) @Biffen